# Разное значение переменной в отладчике и при выводе в консоль

Tags: c++, visual-c++, отладка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал рекурсивный факториал, но при проверке факториала 4 получил 18.
Думал ошибка, вывел в консоль там 24. Подскажите кто в курсе.

Answer (score 4):

Это шестнадцатеричное представление. 0x18 - это и есть 24.

```
8 * 16^0 + 1 * 16^1 = 8 + 16 = 24
```